# Connecting Vaadin Designer to Java Code

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin

I really need your help on a problem with Vaadin Designer.
I developed my own UI with the help of the Designer. So far so good, looks just as I wanted it to look like. But now, where do I get the source code I can edit in order to say what is supposed to happen for when e.g. a button is pressed? I only have the following classes in my Project:
anotherDesign (in which I created the UI),
anotherDesign (which is auto-generated, but must not be edited) and 
MyUI  (standard class).

So if anyone sees my point and could help me, that would be great. Probably that's just because I'm a newbie to Designer and need some general information and help.

Thx anyways,

simon

Comment: I think this is fundamental and is explained in several tutorials. What did you search for on the Internet for an introduction to Vaadin designer? One of the first links I found when using google is [this](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/designer/designer-wiring.html). I didn't work with the designer so far.

Answer (score 1):

FF0000 is absolutely right in that you need to extend the automatically generated companion Java file. Let's take a simple example: you have a Button in a VerticalLayout and the declarative format in `MyDesign.html` looks like this:

```
<vaadin-vertical-layout size-auto> 
    <vaadin-button plain-text _id="button">
        Button 
    </vaadin-button> 
</vaadin-vertical-layout>
```

And then you have your Java companion file `MyDesign.java` which looks something like:

```
@DesignRoot
@AutoGenerated
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyDesign extends VerticalLayout {
    protected Button button;

    public TestDesign() {
        Design.read(this);
    }
}
```

Then in order to add a click listener to the Button, you extend the Java class and access the button. For example:

```
public class MyDesignComponent extends MyDesign {

    public MyDesignComponent() {
        button.addClickListener(e -> Notification.show("Hello world!"));
    }
}
```

And finally in your UI you can use `MyDesignComponent` as you would any other Vaadin component, for example:

```
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        setContent(new MyDesignComponent());
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You write a class that extends the auto-generated class:

```
AnotherDesignExt extends AnotherDesign
```

Comment: I already tried that, but when I deploy the application on my Tomcat server, it shows me the UI that is automatically generated when creating a new project, and not the one that I created. Am I supposed to clean its content and just fill it with the content I want to have, or should I creat another class?

Comment: If you are still having issues, I highly recommend the emailclient tutorial:  https://github.com/vaadin/designer-tutorials/tree/master/emailclient-tutorial and its companion video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6Ix8WHgD6g.